# Terminate batch job in SPFx

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

In spfx, If we press 'ctrl+c' during any continue process then display a message 'Terminate batch job (Y/N)?'
you press Y for yes and N fro No, but both the case y and N terminate the batch job. so it is error or anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree, this is annoying. But it's not spfx that's doing this, it's the command shell itself that controls this behavior. If you google 'Terminate Batch Job' you'll find all sorts of people annoyed by this quirk.